# Access multidimensional Object vars

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I have an Object that looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [users] => stdClass Object
            (
                [831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [lastName] => somename
                        [username] => email@email.com
                        [userExtId] => 831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB
                        [fullName] => somename somename
                        [firstName] => somename
                        [displayName] => bla bla bla
                        [extId] => 831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB
                        [password] => 12345678
                    )
```

Is it possible to access say $object->data->users->lastname ?

EDIT:

```
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d))
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    return is_array($d) ? array_map(__METHOD__, $d) : $d;
}
```

Comment: If you add `->{'831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB'}` yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at using the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php) syntax for this:

```
$object->data->users->{'831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB'}->lastName
```

If you'd like to convert the entire object to an array ([source](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)):

```
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d))
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    return is_array($d) ? array_map(__METHOD__, $d) : $d;
}
```

```
$arr = objectToArray($object);
$arr['data']['users']['831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB']['lastName']
```

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to convert the entire object into an array?

Comment: When using your function, I get this error:
Warning:  array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, 'objectToArray', should be either NULL or a valid callback in /var/www/myclass.php on line 79

Comment: @Bolli:  I'm assuming you placed that function inside of a class, which, as it stands right now, won't work.  To fix this, change the first argument of `array_map` to `__METHOD__` (I have changed this in my answer).

Comment: I only happend to have time to test this today, sadly I am still getting the same error, even though I changed the argument to __METHOD__..  any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bolli:  Just to confirm, you changed the first argument to `__METHOD__`, not `METHOD`?  Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm on PHP 5.3.3-7. And Yes I changed it to `__METHOD__` with the underscores.. Stackoverflow converts it to bold.

Comment: @Bolli:  That seems rather strange.  Perhaps you can edit your original question to include the code where you are placing the `objectToArray` function/method.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$object->data->users->{'831C7119-FAEF-49AF-B95B-50FB492B4ACB'}->lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a multidimensional associative array `$user` with two dimensions, you usually access the named keys like

```
echo $user[413]['name'];
```

if you have an object `$user` with the same structure as the array above, you can access the properties this way

```
echo $user[413]->name;
```